# Prevent Formula From Being Entered Into Unlocked Cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a workbook in which everything is protected except for one cell which updates the filter to a table via a VBA macro on update.  This is almost completely effective at hiding the full contents of the table (at least softly) with one exception: the user can enter a simple formula into the unlocked cell to retrieve any value from the filtered table.

Is there a way to allow user input, but prevent the use of a formula?

Update: It occurs to me that you could do this with a form control, but I'm still wondering if it's possible in a standard cell

Comment: You could have a look at [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/data-validation-to-prevent-formulas/8d5ba3bb-3b38-4a70-bf26-24ecb6e3719d), from the microsoft support forums. I don't have time to write the contents of it into an answer right now, but it should at least contain some pointers for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the problem with doing it via VBA is that the user could always just disable macros